# Spivak Chapter 5 Problem 30 (i); Not understanding proof

Tags: calculus, limits

I have been trying to understand how this proof works to show $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)$ = $\lim_{x \to +0^-} f(-x)$ from here; https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3399848/734140
$$
0 < x < \delta
  \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon
  \implies -\delta < x < 0 
  \implies |f(x) - L|,
$$ 
I don't understand how one can just switch the variables, i'm assuming he just negated the inequality and changed the variable of -x to x, but I was thinking that since -(-x) = x that means $0 < x < \delta \implies 0 < 0-(-x) < \delta$, then by definition of right hand limit, $\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(-x) = L$. Is this reasoning correct or how is the other post correct?

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda like a change of variables, now, we want to prove the limit from below supposing that we have the limit from above, notice that the definition of limit from below of $f(-x)$ is that for every $\epsilon>0 $ there exists $\delta'>0$ so that $$ 0<-x<\delta'\implies |f(-x) -L| < \epsilon  $$ but the definition of the limit from above is $$0 <x < \delta \implies  |f(x)-L| < \epsilon$$ by the definitions provided by the OP. Now suppose that we have the latter, take $y = -x$ now suppose $$ 0<-x<\delta'$$ so $$0<y<\delta'$$ and by the definition of the limit from above taking $\delta = \delta'$  $$0 <y < \delta \implies  |f(y)-L| < \epsilon \implies |f(-x) - L| < \epsilon$$ which is what we wanted to prove.

Comment: But what is the point of changing the variable, it will be the same as -(-x) ? The limit from the left should be 0 - (-x) < δ if im not mistaken?

Comment: @USER149372 I've edited my answer, the link you provided is quite confusing and I suspect the person that answered wasn't using the same definition of limits from above or below, even though they're equivalent.

Comment: Should it also have lim x→0+f(x) is the same as lim y→0+f(y) ?

Comment: @USER149372 No, x = -y not x =y  so lim x→0+ f(-x) is the same as lim y→0+f(y)  or  lim x→0+f(x) is the same as lim y→0-f(y)